# SugarCRM - How to bind (relate) two seperate modules automatically?

Tags: module, sugarcrm

On example I have one Account.
In its subpanel I create Quote for that Account.
In subpanel of that Quote I create two Products for that Quote.
How to automatically relate that two Products for that Account? I want Products to show automatically in subpanel of Account module.

Please if someone can tell me how to bind them and in what custom folder I should put that custom logic. Thank you

Comment: This will require an after-save logic hook, and the installation of a custom subpanel.  This would need to be done using an installable custom package through the Module Loader.  I might be able to put something together, but it might take a bit.

Comment: I solved this. Thank you anyway